# Fingerprint GUI on Thinkpad X1 Carbon

Tags: thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I have a Thinkpad X1 Carbon. I followed [these instructions](https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui), but to no avail.

The output of `lsusb` is:

```
sguha@ajgubi:~$ lsusb  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek  
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 5986:0266 Acer, Inc
```

Comment: I tried everything what can be found via google but my  fingerprint device is not even listed in lsusb. Could someone confirm that working solution exists for Lenovo X1 Carbon 3448-2D9 running ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1):

Why not try the instructions from here? (Disclaimer: haven't tried myself, but might do so if i find the time...)

http://fcns.eu/2012/04/29/fingerprint-reader/

The fingerprint reader on your device should be

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 147e:2020 Upek
```

Comment: Link 404s. Please consider this by adding the context of the link to your answer as per http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm, that finger printer works perfectly on Thinkpad X1 Carbon Touch using fingerprint-gui (http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Fingerprint-GUI) and the experimental libssapi (https://launchpad.net/~fingerprint/+archive/fingerprint-gui-experimental).

Comment: Many of us have reached this page by Googling when having similar issues. I can't see how your answer is helpful in any way. My Thinkpad X1 Carbon does not detect a fingerprint scanner.

Answer (score 0):

The instructions you linked to work just fine on my X1 Carbon 3460-2D3 running Kubuntu 13.04. I could scan and successfully verify prints over the Upek device at 147e:2020. However, I couldn't put it to much use due to the kdm and kscreensaver bugs.